# Linq to SQL " 2 Query "

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

This is my database:

> http://s29.postimg.org/9xgvulvl3/Untitled.jpg

This is my coding:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IList<TicketListModel> TicketList = new List<TicketListModel>();
        var TicketListQuery = from Tickets in db.Tickets
                              select new TicketListModel
                              {
                                  Number = Tickets.Number,
                                  RequestDate = Tickets.RequestDate,
                                  Applicant = (from Applicants in db.Employees where Applicants.ID = Tickets.ID select new { Applicants.Name }).First(),
                                  ComName = ComLibs.Name,
                                  ProbType = Tickets.ProbType,
                                  ProbDetail = Tickets.ProbDetail,
                                  Status = Tickets.Status
                              };
        TicketList = TicketListQuery.ToList();
        return View(TicketList);
    }
```

I'm want to show `Applicant name` but in table `Ticket` the Applicant is a `int`. So just select Applicant name in table Employee where Applicant ID equals Employee ID then select a Employee name.

Please help me thanks.

Comment: What is your question? Do you have an error?

Comment: `N+1` question? And the picture is too small

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use `Linq Join`

```
IList<TicketListModel> TicketList = (from t in db.Tickets
                        join e in db.Employees on t.ID equals e.ID
                        select new TicketListModel
                        {
                            Number = t.Number,
                            RequestDate = t.RequestDate,
                            Applicant = e.Name,
                            ComName = ComLibs.Name,
                            ProbType = t.ProbType,
                            ProbDetail = t.ProbDetail,
                            Status = t.Status
                        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IList<TicketListModel> TicketList = new List<TicketListModel>();
    var TicketListQuery = from t in db.Tickets

                          select new TicketListModel
                          {
                              Number = t.Number,
                              RequestDate = t.RequestDate,
                              Applicant = (from a in db.Employees where a.ID = t.ID select a.Name).FirstOrDefault(),
                              ComName = ComLibs.Name,
                              ProbType = t.ProbType,
                              ProbDetail = t.ProbDetail,
                              Status = t.Status
                          };
    TicketList = TicketListQuery.ToList();
    return View(TicketList);
}
```

OR

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IList<TicketListModel> TicketList = new List<TicketListModel>();
    var TicketListQuery = from t in db.Tickets
                          from a in db.Employees
                          where t.ID == a.ID
                          select new TicketListModel
                          {
                              t.Number,
                              t.RequestDate,
                              Applicant = a.Name,
                              ComName = ComLibs.Name,
                              t.ProbType,
                              t.ProbDetail,
                              t.Status
                          };
    TicketList = TicketListQuery.ToList();
    return View(TicketList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the right foreign key constraints and that you're using Entity Framework, so I think you should be able to simplify and do it like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IList<TicketListModel> TicketList = new List<TicketListModel>();
    var TicketListQuery = from t in db.Tickets
                          select new TicketListModel
                          {
                              Number = t.Number,
                              RequestDate = t.RequestDate,
                              Applicant = t.Applicant.Name,
                              ComName = t.ComLib.Name,
                              ProbType = t.ProbType,
                              ProbDetail = t.ProbDetail,
                              Status = t.Status
                          };
    TicketList = TicketListQuery.ToList();
    return View(TicketList);
}
```